# Getting parseerror while receiving response from json_encode using $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to try a pretty simple request and get response thing using $.ajax via. json. I have tried alot to return a simple text phrase from a php file.
My js part of code goes like this that calls a beemailer.php to get response.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'beemailer.php',
        data: {
            'name': data_name,
            'email': data_email,
            'message': data_message,
            'subject': data_subject
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var output = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(output);
            alert(output);
        },
        error: function (error, x, y) {
            console.log(error);
            alert(x, y);

        }
        )
};
```

And beemailer.php is like this:

```
<?php
    $to = "ashish_sharma307@hotmail.com";
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message =$_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:".$_POST['name']."(".$_POST['email'].")";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    $response = "The mail has been sent. Thank You the valid mail.";
     header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
     echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

What I need for now is simply to get that $response text get alerted. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove below code from `ajax` call and try:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

`jQuery.parseJSON(data)` is not needed as `Content-Type` is set and encoded in `json` by below code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Updated code with test data:

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url  : 'beemailer.php',
    data: {name: 'rai', email: 'rai@test.com', message: 'Test message', subject: 'Test subject'},
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(error, x, y)
    {
        console.log(error);
        alert(x, y);
    }
});
```

PHP (beemailer.php)

```
<?php
$to = "ashish_sharma307@hotmail.com";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From:" . $_POST['name'] . "(" . $_POST['email'] . ")";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
$response = "The mail has been sent. Thank You the valid mail.";
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Example of object:

```
$result = array();
$result['status'] = 'success';
$result['message'] = 'The mail has been sent. Thank You the valid mail.';
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode($result);
```

JS to access object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url  : 'beemailer.php',
    data: {name: 'rai', email: 'rai@test.com', message: 'Test message', subject: 'Test subject'},
    success : function(data) {
        alert('status: ' + data.status + '\nmessage: ' + data.message);
    },
    error: function(error, x, y)
    {
        console.log(error);
        alert(x, y);
    }
});
```

Comment: tried this but getting undefined data alerted even after getting response in a array wrap. Along with the following response.



.........
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0002</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>680008</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\ashishsharma.com.np\beemailer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\beemailer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
{"message":"The mail has been sent. Thank You the valid mail."}

Comment: That means you have errors in your `beemailer.php` file, may be because of `mail function`

Comment: I just commented mail() function and just returned a simple text as response which is still not working.

Comment: I have updated the answer, try `Updated code with test data:`

Comment: Thanks manoj, after trying different techniques, with the above code you've suggested, everything is fine but we need to return $response in an object wrap lets say an array as $array = array($response); echo json_encode($array); and alerting an data in success as alert(output[0]). And for my particular case, i came to know I could have used dataType: 'text' and returned response in a way as I and You have returned.

Comment: no use dataType: `json` only, you can return response in object format and can access it like `data[0]` or `data['somekey']`

Comment: yeah exactly..sorry, I didn't noticed your $result array. You are absolutely right. And I got my solution.Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you've said `dataType: "json"`, jQuery will parse the JSON for you before calling your `success` function, so what you're passing into `parseJSON` is already an object graph, not a string. Take out that call and rather than using `output`, just use `data` directly.

However, what you're returning from your PHP is not a valid JSON document, it's just a JSON *fragment* (a string). A JSON *document* must always have a top-level object or array ([more](http://json.org)). So you need to wrap that string in either an object or an array.

Also, note that you're using the `contentType` option incorrectly. That defines the type of what you're **sending**, not the type of what you expect to receive.

For instance:

```
$response = "The mail has been sent. Thank You the valid mail.";
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode(array(message => $response));
```

...and then in your `success` function:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data.message);
}
```

Note how the key I used in the PHP (`message`) became a key in the resulting deserialized JSON on the client.

This complete example works:

PHP (`test.php`):

```
<?php
    $response = 'This is a test message. You sent: ' . $_POST['param'];
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8', true);
    echo json_encode(array(message => $response));
?>
```

HTML and Script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:    'POST',
    url:     'test.php',
    data:    {param: 'Test param'},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.message);
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

In a comment below you said:

> Can you please explain...about why I am not getting a text as response while returning a text.

You're returning **JSON**, which is a textual representation of an object graph.

Absolutely you can return just text if you want. To do that, don't involve JSON. Here's an example, but it won't solve the problem you're having of getting extraneous HTML output before your message, which is something happening in your PHP:

PHP (`test.php`):

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8', true);
    $response = 'This is a test message. You sent: ' . $_POST['param'];
    echo $response;
?>
```

HTML and Script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:    'POST',
    url:     'test.php',
    data:    {param: 'Test param'},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @accssharma: Did you see the bit about your PHP outputting an invalid JSON document? I've just edited to give you a bit more direction.

Comment: Nope I haven't yet but have been researching focused on this particular problem. And it's again not working even after wrapping response in an array.

Comment: Am I doing   header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true); this part correctly?

Comment: @accssharma: Looks right to me. (And if you have that, you don't actually need the `dataType: "JSON"` on the jQuery, it'll see the `Content-Type`. It's harmless, I'm just saying.)

Comment: @accssharma: I just noticed you're passing the `contentType` option in the `ajax` call, which is almost certainly incorrect, so I've mentioned that. I've also posted a complete example that works.

Comment: Did that. Actually I was aware of that but trying it from few hours back, I had added that to check if anything that I wanted comes up. Doing as per your answer above a long response I got is:

.........
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0002</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>680008</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\ashishsharma.com.np\beemailer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\beemailer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
{"message":"The mail has been sent. Thank You the valid mail."}

Comment: @accssharma: That means something in your PHP is sending HTML before the JSON. Looks like some kind of tracing information, or possibly output generated by the call to `mail`. Nothing to do with the JSON encoding or the client-side stuff.

Comment: Its getting undefined alerted even if i comment that mailing funciton.
Can you please explain (or redirect me to such document ) about why I am not getting a text as response while returning a text. Is the response necessarily be object wrapped? Can't we just return a text or integer as response so that we can just get data by doing alert(data).

Comment: @accssharma: I suggest you step back and do some reading. You're using [JSON](http://json.org). JSON is a textual representation of an object graph. Yes, absolutely, you can just return text if you want to. In that case, just return text, not JSON. I've added another example. But you'll still get that extraneous HTML until/unless you sort that out.

Comment: Thank you for making many things clear. For this particular question. I got two solutions.
With my code.
Solution1: Remove contentType, use dataType: 'Text' return a simple text as echo json_encode($response) and alert inside success as alert(output) and Solution2: Remove contentType, use dataType: 'json', return a response in a array wrap as $array = array($response); echo json_encode($array); and alert using indexing like alert(output[0]) inside success.

Answer (score 0):

Your server may have returned notice/warning. please disable your error reporting sometime to test . error_reporting(0), this works for me in php 5.4.

Hope this will help someone facing same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just found something absolutely crazy about PHP `json_encode` and JS AJAX `parseerror`.  If it helps one person that'll justify my including it here.

I was getting totally inexplicable `parseerror`s with the return of an object involving the simplest of possible PHP objects: just a normal string key and a short string value.

When I'm putting development logging messages in my code I typically put a "£" at the start of messages, just to make it easier to locate them sometimes.  Inadvertently I had put a "£" at the start of this message to be returned to the JS AJAX handling... and it was **THIS** which was causing a `parseerror`!

I would personally regard this as a bug ... and am amazed to find it in 2017. I have no idea why a leading "£" might have this effect, and wonder (naturally) whether other characters (leading or otherwise) can have the effect of causing a `parseerror`.

I just did a search on this and found one person mentioning a problem with the pound symbol [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/757-learning-coldfusion-8-javascript-object-notation-json-part-i---data-conversion.htm) (2011).

When you're submitting SQL statements to `mysqli` you have to put them through an escape function ... this experience makes me wonder whether one is not maybe needed for strings going from PHP to an JS AJAX handler...?

Any experts care to comment?